# MVC Grid without refreshing whole page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid

I'm want to implement paging in Grid in MVC4 application with paging. In paging i can send all data to the client and then to let it pages and sorts all data received 
(For this i saw lot of jquery grids but i suspect it will fail if number of rows will increase) or prefer doing this operation on the server and sending to the client JUST ONE PAGE OF DATA (I want some jquery or ajax type implementation where I will send the JSON data fro the server to client without any refresh of whole view. Is there any out of box implemtation using Jquery or JSon)

Answer (score 0):

I use `HTML.Pager` in my Asp.net MVC application for paging. Just check the demo over [here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/09/18/asp-net-mvc-tip-44-create-a-pager-html-helper.aspx) . It might help you